# Can't create input when data null with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a sample code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function remove_news(id) {
    try {
        $('news_list').removeChild($('news_'+id));
        $('news_list').removeChild($('input_news_'+id));
        if($('news_list') == '') {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            input.setAttribute("name", "news_id");
            input.setAttribute("value", "0");
            document.getElementById("news_list").appendChild(input);
        }
    } catch(err){}
}
</script>
<div id="news_list">
<div id='news_1'> News no 1 <a href='#' onclick='remove_news(1); return false;'>[Delete]</a></div>
<input type="hidden" id="input_news_1" name="news_id" value="1" />
</div>
```

When I run code, chose delete link is result not show `<input type="hidden" name="news_id" value="0" />`

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using `#news_id`, etc as the jQuery selector with `#`:

```
try {
    $('#news_list').removeChild($('#news_'+id));
    $('#news_list').removeChild($('#input_news_'+id));
    if($('#news_list').html() == '') {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        input.setAttribute("name", "news_id");
        input.setAttribute("value", "0");
        document.getElementById("news_list").appendChild(input);
    }
 } catch(err){}
```

However, you needn't mix jQuery and regular JavaScript. Since you're using jQuery, you might as well use all jQuery.  I won't guarantee the above would even work.

```
try {
    // Instead of removing a child node, just remove the element directly:
    $('#news_'+id).remove()
    $('#input_news_'+id).remove();
    if($('#news_list').html() == '') {
        var input = $.create("<input type='hidden' name='news_id' value='0'>");
        $('#news_list').append(input);
    }
 } catch(err){}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether an object exists, don't compare the jQuery object to an empty string.

```
if($('news_list') == '') { ...}
```

Check for a nonzero length. And as someone else mentioned, it looks like you are missing hashes to identify your elements.

```
if($('#news_list').length == 0) { ...}
```

In addition the logic in this if statement seems flawed. You check if `news_list` is there, but then you try and get an element by that same id in the last line. Little hard to tell because as I mentioned you are querying an object against a string. That doesn't make sense.

```
    if($('news_list') == '') {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        input.setAttribute("name", "news_id");
        input.setAttribute("value", "0");
        document.getElementById("news_list").appendChild(input); //doesn't exist?
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand it correctly, and seeing you use jQuery:

```
function remove_news(id) {
    var newsList = $('#news_list');          //cache news list

    $('#news_'+id,newsList).remove();       //then remove the news
    $('#input_news_'+id,newsList).remove(); //as well as the accompanying input

    if(newsList.length){                    //and if there is no news left
        $('<input type="hidden">').attr({   //create a hidden input
            'name':'news_id',               
            'value':'0'
        }).appendTo(newsList);              //and append to list
    }
}
```

the explanation of `$('<input type="hidden">')` is that [IE does not support doing dynamic input changing](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) like `$('<input>').attr({'type':'hidden'})`

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

```
> function remove_news(id) {
>      try {
```

There is absolutely no need for try..catch here. Code defensively, not in a padded cell.

```
>          $('news_list').removeChild($('news_'+id));
>          $('news_list').removeChild($('input_news_'+id));
```

You seem conflicted between jQuery and plain javascript, so:

```
  var news_list = document.getElementById('news_' + id);
  news_list && news_list.parentNode.removeChild(news_list);

  var input_news_list = document.getElementById('input_news_' + id);
  input_news_list && input_news_list.parentNode.removeChild(input_news_list);

> 
>          if($('news_list') == '') {
```

You just removed that element from the DOM, so you won't find it there. Comparing it to an empty string is a poor choice as well, I presume this is a test to see if the element is in the document. Since it is unnecessary, It can be removed.

```
>              var input = document.createElement('input');
>              input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
>              input.setAttribute("name", "news_id");
>              input.setAttribute("value", "0");
```

Why do all that if all yoy want to do is clear the value? Anyhow, simpler to ditch the setAttribute calls and just set properties directly:

```
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'hidden';
  input.name = 'news_id';
  input.value = '0';

>              document.getElementById("news_list").appendChild(input);
>          }     
>     } catch(err){}  }
```

Ih the HTML (my wrapping for convenience):

```
> <div id='news_1'> News no 1 <a href='#' onclick='remove_news(1);
>  return false;'>[Delete]</a></div>
```

Why use an A element when you don't want one? Use a span and style it appropriately (or, heaven forbid, a button):

```
<div ...><span onclick="remove_news(1);">...</span></div>
```

You can make the function more generic by using the id of the div so you don't ahve to pass it in the call. Then you can probably just attach one listener to an ancestor that sees where the click came from and works it out from there (i.e. delegate).